# Computation on db data then list them using either SimpleCursorAdapter or ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I juststarted programming in android a few weeks ago, so I am not entirely sure how to deal with listing values. Please help me out!
I have some questions regarding displaying data sets from db in a list. Currently I have a cursor returned by my db points to a list of rows and I want display 2 columns values in a single row of the list. The row xml looks like this:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

so I was thinking using simplecursoradapter which supposedly makes my life easier by displaying the data in a list. However that is only true if I want to display the raw data. 
For the purpose of my program I need to do some computations on the raw data sets, then display them. I am not sure how to do that using SimpleCursorAdapter. Here's how I display the raw data:

```
   String[] from = new String[]{BtDbAdapter.KEY_EX_TYPE,BtDbAdapter.KEY_EX_TIMESTAMP};

   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter records = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.exset_row, mExsetCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(records);
```

Is there a way to do computation on the data in those rows before I bind it with the SimpleCursorAdapter? I was trying to use an alternative way of doing this by using arraylist and arrayadapter, but that way I dont know to how achieve displaying 2 items in a single row.

This is my code for using arrayadapter which only display 1 text in a row instead of 2 textviews in a row:

```
  //fill in the array
  timestamp_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
  type_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
  fillRecord();

  Log.d(TAG,"setting now in recordlist");
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,timestamp_arr));
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item2,type_arr));
```

It's very obvious that it only displays one textview in a row because I set the second arrayadapter overwrites the first one! I was trying to use R.id.text1 and R.id.text2 for them, but it gave me some errors saying 
04-23 01:40:58.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3309): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070008 type #0x12 is not valid

I believe the second method can achieve this, but I'm not sure how do deal with the layout problems, so if you any suggestions, please post them out. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` is just what it is, errr simple. More elaborate requirements require different adapters. In your case, switch to `ResourceCursorAdapter` and overwrite `bindView()`. Call `view.findViewById(R.id.text1)`, fetch data from the cursor, do your modifications and set the text to the view.

I would avoid switching to `ArrayAdapter` in your case. E.g. you can easily refresh a cursor adapter, it will consume less resources and scale better.